# Not sure why newly created Lookup type column [Update Date] is not auto-populating

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column

[image]

[image]

[image]

Shouldn't the lookup operation automatically create a relationship between the common [Issue Index] columns (both type Number), then populate the [Update Date] lookup column with the matching values?

Nothing is happening. What am I doing wrong?

I don't remember having any difficulty in previous attempts.

Also, "Allow Multiple Selections" is enabled.